# Why did Francesca Campbell betray Red?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-blacklist

In Season 7 of *The Blacklist*, Francesca Campbell at first decides to help Red, seemingly having a conscience and principles, then she fails the test by betraying him.

Why did she betray him? Is there an explanation for this seemingly contradictory behaviour?

Comment: May I ask what your question is?

Comment: What is this a compiler error; you really can't figure out what I'm asking: Can you explain please the seemingly contradiction?

Comment: I *assume* you're asking us to explain the nurse's contradictory behaviour, but that's not at all clear, as your post doesn't actually contain a question at the moment. Could you [edit] to make it clearer?

Comment: Actually, since you already clarified in the previous comment, I can just make the edit for you.

Comment: Sometimes a few more words of context help more than throwing a random sentence into the void and hoping everyone else imagines you making a "huh?" face (and acting weird in comments when they don't). Unless you're right in a *Blacklist* exam and posting this from your phone in the bathroom break, I'm sure you have the 1 minute more it requires to add one or two sentences and make it a proper question people can answer. ;-)